# Flutter - whenComplete() not working as expected when using Providers

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm trying to display a loading while doing an API Request and when finished to show the list with the response or a custom widget to show a message(EmptyListWidget). The problem is that the whenComplete() method is being executed before the async function is finished.

I also tried using then() and using FutureBuilder but I also can't make it work using Provider (allways returns null).

If someone could help, I would really appreciate it.. thanks :)

My List Widget:

```
class _AbsencesListState extends State<AbsencesList> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _isInit = true;

  @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_isInit) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
      Provider.of<AbsencesTypes>(context, listen: false)
          .getAbsencesTypes(widget.ctx)
          .whenComplete(() {
        setState(() => _isLoading = false);
      });
      _isInit = false;
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final absences = Provider.of<Absences>(context).items;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _isLoading
            ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : absences.length > 0
                ? Container()
                : EmptyListWidget(ListType.InconsistenciesList),
        ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Card(
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    child: const Icon(Icons.sick),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  title: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                    child: Text(absences[index].absenceType.name),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    absences[index].firstDate
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: absences.length,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The async function:

```
class AbsencesTypes with ChangeNotifier {
  List<AbsenceType> _absencesTypesList = [];

  List<AbsenceType> get items {
    return [..._absencesTypesList];
  }

  void emptyAbsencesTypeList() {
    _absencesTypesList.clear();
  }

  Future<void> getAbsencesTypes(BuildContext context) async {
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = _prefs.getString(TOKEN_KEY);
    http.get(
      API_URL,
      headers: {"Authorization": token},
    ).then(
      (http.Response response) async {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          final apiResponse = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
          final extractedData = apiResponse['content'];
          final List<AbsenceType> loadedAbsencesTypes = [];
          for (var absenceType in extractedData) {
            loadedAbsencesTypes.add(
              AbsenceType(
                id: absenceType["id"],
                name: absenceType["name"].toString(),
                code: absenceType["code"].toString(),
                totalAllowedDays: absenceType["totalAllowedDays"],
              ),
            );
          }
          _absencesTypesList = loadedAbsencesTypes;
        } else if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          Utility.showToast(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("expired_session_string"));
          Utility.sendUserToLogin(_prefs, context);
        }
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `final absences = Provider.of<Absences>(context).items;` and not `final absences = Provider.of<AbsencesTypes>(context).items;`?

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I forgot to change it when posting this question, but my issue has already been solved, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is probably that you're calling `http.get` without awaiting for it's result.
The `getAbsencesTypes` returns the `Future<void>` as soon as the `http.get` method is executed, without waiting for the answer, and it results in your `onComplete` method to be triggered.

A simple fix would be to add the `await` keyword before the `http.get`, but you could do even better.

In your code, you're not fully using the `ChangeNotifierProvider` which could solve your problem. You should check the [Consumer](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html) class which will be pretty useful for you here, but since it's not your initial question I won't go more in depth on this subject.

Comment: The `await` keyword solved the problem. My bad :D Thanks!